# Creating alphanumeric sequence in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

By using excel, I need to create an alphanumeric sequence of 4 letters/numbers starting from 0000 up to ZZZZ.
I created a little macro like the one below:

```
Sub a()
Dim iChar1 As Integer, iChar2 As Integer, iChar3 As Integer, iChar4 As Integer
Dim sOutput As String
For iChar1 = 65 To 90
For iChar2 = 65 To 90
For iChar3 = 65 To 90
For iChar4 = 65 To 90
sOutput = Chr(iChar1) & Chr(iChar2) & Chr(iChar3) & iChar4

ActiveCell.Value = sOutput
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next: Next: Next: Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that in this way I obtain only alpha sequence due to ASCII caracheters from 65 to 90. Instead, I need also numeric values, (ASCII from 48 to 57).
How to do it? Or, do you know an alternative way?

Comment: Why not create an array of the values you want to loop through and then just `For Each` through that array 4 times in the same nested fashion??

Comment: @JohnBustos  + 1 a very good and elegant solution

Comment: Thank you for your solution, can you please explain it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps like this, using an input array and output array rather than writing cell by cell

```
Sub a()
   Dim vChars
   Dim iChar1 As Integer, iChar2 As Integer, iChar3 As Integer, iChar4 As Integer
   Dim sOut(1 To 839808, 1 To 2) As String
   Dim lCounter As Long
   Dim lCol As Long
   vChars = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", _
                           "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
   lCounter = 1
   lCol = 1
   For iChar1 = 0 To 35
      For iChar2 = 0 To 35
         For iChar3 = 0 To 35
            For iChar4 = 0 To 35
               sOut(lCounter, lCol) = vChars(iChar1) & vChars(iChar2) & vChars(iChar3) & vChars(iChar4)
               If lCounter = 839808 Then
                  lCol = 2
                  lCounter = 1
               Else
                  lCounter = lCounter + 1
               End If

            Next iChar4
         Next iChar3
      Next iChar2
   Next iChar1
Range("A1").Resize(839808, 2).Value = sOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Very good solution! Thank you. A question: Why do you splitted it into two columns?

Comment: because there are too many combinations to fit in one column of a worksheet ;-)